# Why doesn't the C++/CLI compiler generate warnings for Obsolete property calls?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, compiler-warnings, api-design

I'm referencing a 3rd party .NET library from some C++/CLI code. My C++/CLI calling code is referencing a property that has been marked Obsolete in a C# library using the Obsolete attribute:

```cs
// C# External library code
using System;
namespace ExternalLibrary
{
    public class Dependency
    {
        [Obsolete("Please use the new version.")]
        public static bool IsInitialized
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I compile my C++/CLI calling code that uses the property, it does not generate any obsolete/deprecated warnings (e.g. C4947), even if I set the Warning Level to `/Wall EnableAllWarnings`.

If I reference the same API from C# code, I get the expected CS0618 warning, telling me that the property is obsolete, but when I compile the C++/CLI code, I do not receive any obsoletion or deprecation warnings.

```cs
// C# Calling code (in another assembly)
namespace CalledFromCSharp
{
    public class CSharpCode
    {
        public static void CallingCode()
        {
            // Generates warning CS0618:
            //   'ExternalLibrary.Dependency.IsInitialized' is obsolete:
            //   'Please use the new version.'
            bool initialized = ExternalLibrary.Dependency.IsInitialized;
        }
    }
}
```

```cpp
// C++/CLI Calling code (also in another assembly)
#pragma once
using namespace System;
namespace CppCode
{
    public ref class CalledFromCpp
    {
        static void CallingCode()
        {
            // NO OBSOLETE WARNING GENERATED
            bool isInitialized = ExternalLibrary::Dependency::IsInitialized;
        };
    };
}
```

This seems to happen for both static and non-static property calls. Is there something extra that I need to set in my C++/CLI project (using Visual Studio 2013) to get an appropriate warning to show up? Or is there a reason for the current behavior?

Comment: C++/CLI won't ever produce a `CS0618` warning: `CS` means *C#*. It should generate [C4947](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kasyftc.aspx) instead but it looks like there's no VS2013 equivalent.

Comment: Good point! I edited the original text to try to improve the clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Hmya, hate to be the bearer of bad news but the C++/CLI designers did properties differently.  Somewhat obvious from their syntax, they favored the "similar to C++" approach in many of their choices.  Best demonstrated by modifying your code snippet:

```
public ref class CalledFromCpp {
public:
    static property bool Foo {
        [Obsolete("This works")]
        bool get() { return false; }
    }
    [Obsolete("This doesn't work")]
    static property bool Bar {
        bool get() { return false;  }
    }
    static void CallingCode() {
        bool test1 = CalledFromCpp::Foo;   // Yes
        bool test2 = CalledFromCpp::Bar;   // Nope
        bool test3 = ExternalLibrary::Dependency::IsInitialized;  // Nope
    }
};
```

You cannot do the same on the C# property, it won't permit you to apply the [Obsolete] attribute on the getter.  There is no workaround for this.

Comment: That appears to be a C# bug... the `ObsoleteAttribute` class explicitly declares that it can be used with methods, and C# does allow custom attributes with `AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)` to be applied to accessors.

Comment: ...and since `ObsoleteAttribute` is also marked with `AttributeTargets.Property`, this looks like a C++/CLI compiler bug/oversight.